# Updating fragment text view from Activity - Nullpointerexception

Tags: android, android-fragments

Being sort of new in the Android topic, I've been reading and taking courses/tutorials here and there. I understand the Activity deal but now I'm into fragments and trying to put a simple app together using the google Calendar API. However, I'm having a really hard time grasping the "updating Fragment" from MainActivity part.

At this point, the app just crashes
I've tried just about everything to make this work but have had no success :( How do you go about this??

Here's the MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity
    implements NavigationDrawerFragment.NavigationDrawerCallbacks {

com.google.api.services.calendar.Calendar mService;

GoogleAccountCredential credential;
public TextView mStatusText;
public TextView mEventText;

final HttpTransport transport = AndroidHttp.newCompatibleTransport();
final JsonFactory jsonFactory = GsonFactory.getDefaultInstance();


static final int REQUEST_ACCOUNT_PICKER = 1000;
static final int REQUEST_AUTHORIZATION = 1001;
static final int REQUEST_GOOGLE_PLAY_SERVICES = 1002;
private static final String PREF_ACCOUNT_NAME = "accountName";
private static final String[] SCOPES = {CalendarScopes.CALENDAR_READONLY};

/**
 * Fragment managing the behaviors, interactions and presentation of the navigation drawer.
 */
private NavigationDrawerFragment mNavigationDrawerFragment;

/**
 * Used to store the last screen title. For use in {@link #restoreActionBar()}.
 */
private CharSequence mTitle;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mNavigationDrawerFragment = (NavigationDrawerFragment)
            getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.navigation_drawer);
    mTitle = getTitle();

    // Set up the drawer.
    mNavigationDrawerFragment.setUp(
            R.id.navigation_drawer,
            (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout));

    // Initialize credentials and calendar service.
    SharedPreferences settings = getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    credential = GoogleAccountCredential.usingOAuth2(
            getApplicationContext(), Arrays.asList(SCOPES))
            .setBackOff(new ExponentialBackOff())
            .setSelectedAccountName(settings.getString(PREF_ACCOUNT_NAME, null));

    mService = new com.google.api.services.calendar.Calendar.Builder(
            transport, jsonFactory, credential)
            .setApplicationName("Calendar API Android Quickstart")
            .build();


}

@Override
public void onNavigationDrawerItemSelected(int position) {

    Fragment fragment = null;

    switch (position) {
        case 0:
           fragment = new Noticias_Fragment();
            break;
        case 1:
            fragment = new Eventos_Fragment();

            break;
        case 2:
           fragment = new Quienes_Fragment();
            break;
        case 3:
            fragment = new Contacto_Fragment();
            break;
    }
    // update the main content by replacing fragments
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
    fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.container, fragment)
            .commit();
}


public void onSectionAttached(int number) {
    switch (number) {
        case 1:
            mTitle = getString(R.string.title_section1);
            break;
        case 2:
            mTitle = getString(R.string.title_section2);
            break;
        case 3:
            mTitle = getString(R.string.title_section3);
            break;
        case 4:
            mTitle = getString(R.string.title_section4);
            break;

    }
}

public void restoreActionBar() {
    ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_STANDARD);
    actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
    actionBar.setTitle(mTitle);
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    if (!mNavigationDrawerFragment.isDrawerOpen()) {
        // Only show items in the action bar relevant to this screen
        // if the drawer is not showing. Otherwise, let the drawer
        // decide what to show in the action bar.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        restoreActionBar();
        return true;
    }
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

/**
 * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
 */
public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {
    /**
     * The fragment argument representing the section number for this
     * fragment.
     */
    private static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

    /**
     * Returns a new instance of this fragment for the given section
     * number.
     */
    public static PlaceholderFragment newInstance(int sectionNumber) {
        PlaceholderFragment fragment = new PlaceholderFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, sectionNumber);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    public PlaceholderFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        ((MainActivity) activity).onSectionAttached(
                getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER));
    }
}


public void ButtonOnClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.imageButton: //botón Mail
            Intent emailIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            emailIntent.setType("text/plain");
            emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{"elmaildefresh@gmail.com"});
            emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Motivo");
            emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Escribe tu texto a enviar");
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Elije tu gestor de correo..."));
            break;
        case R.id.imageButton2: //botón Página
            Intent intent2 = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            intent2.setData(Uri.parse("http://www.lapaginadelfreshxalapa.com"));
            startActivity(intent2);
            break;
        case R.id.imageButton3: //botón FB
            Intent intent3 = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            intent3.setData(Uri.parse("http://www.facebook.com/freshxalapa"));
            startActivity(intent3);
            break;
        case R.id.imageButton4: //botón TW
            Intent intent4 = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            intent4.setData(Uri.parse("http://www.twitter.com/freshxalapa"));
            startActivity(intent4);
            break;

    }
}

/**
 * Called whenever this activity is pushed to the foreground, such as after
 * a call to onCreate().
 */

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    if (isGooglePlayServicesAvailable()) {
        refreshEventList();
    } else {

        mStatusText.setText("Google Play Services required: " +
                "after installing, close and relaunch this app.");
    }
}

/**
 * Called when an activity launched here (specifically, AccountPicker
 * and authorization) exits, giving you the requestCode you started it with,
 * the resultCode it returned, and any additional data from it.
 * @param requestCode code indicating which activity result is incoming.
 * @param resultCode code indicating the result of the incoming
 *     activity result.
 * @param data Intent (containing result data) returned by incoming
 *     activity result.
 */
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(
        int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    switch(requestCode) {
        case REQUEST_GOOGLE_PLAY_SERVICES:
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                refreshEventList();
            } else {
                isGooglePlayServicesAvailable();
            }
            break;
        case REQUEST_ACCOUNT_PICKER:
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null &&
                    data.getExtras() != null) {
                String accountName =
                        data.getStringExtra(AccountManager.KEY_ACCOUNT_NAME);
                if (accountName != null) {
                    credential.setSelectedAccountName(accountName);
                    SharedPreferences settings =
                            getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
                    editor.putString(PREF_ACCOUNT_NAME, accountName);
                    editor.commit();
                    refreshEventList();
                }
            } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
                mStatusText.setText("Account unspecified.");
            }
            break;
        case REQUEST_AUTHORIZATION:
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                refreshEventList();
            } else {
                chooseAccount();
            }
            break;
    }

    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}

/**
 * Attempt to get a list of calendar events to display. If the email
 * address isn't known yet, then call chooseAccount() method so the user
 * can pick an account.
 */
private void refreshEventList() {
    if (credential.getSelectedAccountName() == null) {
        chooseAccount();
    } else {
        if (isDeviceOnline()) {
            new EventsFetchTask(this).execute();
        } else {
            mStatusText.setText("No network connection available.");
        }
    }
}

/**
 * Clear any existing events from the list display and update the header
 * message; called from background threads and async tasks that need to
 * update the UI (in the UI thread).
 */
public void clearEvents() {
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            mStatusText.setText("Retrieving events…");
            mEventText.setText("");
        }
    });
}

/**
 * Fill the event display with the given List of strings; called from
 * background threads and async tasks that need to update the UI (in the
 * UI thread).
 * @param eventStrings a List of Strings to populate the event display with.
 */
public void updateEventList(final List<String> eventStrings) {
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            if (eventStrings == null) {
                mStatusText.setText("Error retrieving events!");
            } else if (eventStrings.size() == 0) {
                mStatusText.setText("No upcoming events found.");
            } else {
                mStatusText.setText("Your upcoming events retrieved using" +
                        " the Google Calendar API:");
                mEventText.setText(TextUtils.join("\n\n", eventStrings));
            }
        }
    });
}

/**
 * Show a status message in the list header TextView; called from background
 * threads and async tasks that need to update the UI (in the UI thread).
 * @param message a String to display in the UI header TextView.
 */
public void updateStatus(final String message) {
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            mStatusText.setText(message);
        }
    });
}

/**
 * Starts an activity in Google Play Services so the user can pick an
 * account.
 */
private void chooseAccount() {
    startActivityForResult(
            credential.newChooseAccountIntent(), REQUEST_ACCOUNT_PICKER);
}

/**
 * Checks whether the device currently has a network connection.
 * @return true if the device has a network connection, false otherwise.
 */
private boolean isDeviceOnline() {
    ConnectivityManager connMgr =
            (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo networkInfo = connMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    return (networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnected());
}

/**
 * Check that Google Play services APK is installed and up to date. Will
 * launch an error dialog for the user to update Google Play Services if
 * possible.
 * @return true if Google Play Services is available and up to
 *     date on this device; false otherwise.
 */
private boolean isGooglePlayServicesAvailable() {
    final int connectionStatusCode =
            GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);
    if (GooglePlayServicesUtil.isUserRecoverableError(connectionStatusCode)) {
        showGooglePlayServicesAvailabilityErrorDialog(connectionStatusCode);
        return false;
    } else if (connectionStatusCode != ConnectionResult.SUCCESS ) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

/**
 * Display an error dialog showing that Google Play Services is missing
 * or out of date.
 * @param connectionStatusCode code describing the presence (or lack of)
 *     Google Play Services on this device.
 */
void showGooglePlayServicesAvailabilityErrorDialog(
        final int connectionStatusCode) {
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Dialog dialog = GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(
                    connectionStatusCode,
                    MainActivity.this,
                    REQUEST_GOOGLE_PLAY_SERVICES);
            dialog.show();
        }
    });
}
}
```

And here's the Fragment:

```
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Eventos_Fragment extends Fragment {
View rootView;

/**
 * A Calendar service object used to query or modify calendars via the
 * Calendar API. Note: Do not confuse this class with the
 * com.google.api.services.calendar.model.Calendar class.
 */


 TextView mStatusText;
 TextView mEventText;



@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {


    rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_evento, container, false);
    //Set up event text views for Google API

    return rootView;
}

public void changeStatusText(){
    //this textview should be bound in the fragment onCreate as a member variable
    mStatusText = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.status_text_view);
    mStatusText.setText("Estatus");
}

public void changeEventText(){
    //this textview should be bound in the fragment onCreate as a member variable
    mEventText = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.event_text_view);
    mEventText.setText("Evento");
}

}
```

The log:

```
04-28 18:38:46.751    1557-1557/mx.com.origamilab.fresh E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: mx.com.origamilab.fresh, PID: 1557
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {mx.com.origamilab.fresh/mx.com.origamilab.fresh.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2774)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2803)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2238)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at mx.com.origamilab.fresh.MainActivity.onResume(MainActivity.java:258)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnResume(Instrumentation.java:1192)
            at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:5310)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2764)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2803)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2238)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Your stacktrace says it is NullPointerException at #258, I think mStatusText is null. can you move mStatusText = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.status_text_view); in onCreateView()

Comment: Just for your reference: CodePath have very good Android tutorials here https://guides.codepath.com/android#fragments

Comment: Thanks, did that and tried it out but, it throws a java.lang.NullPointerException on MainActivity.onResume

Comment: Which is this:  @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        if (isGooglePlayServicesAvailable()) {
            refreshEventList();
        } else {

            mStatusText.setText("Google Play Services required: " +
                    "after installing, close and relaunch this app.");
        }
    }

Answer (score 0):

Try this

Replace

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
        .replace(R.id.container, fragment)
        .commit();
```

with

```
android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.container, fragment).commit();
```

Comment: Tried it, and for this one, it tells me that it cannot resolve method getSupportFragmentManager :/

Answer (score 0):

mStatusText is never initialized to anything in your MainActivity.  That's why you're getting a NullPointerException.

You'll need to initialize it with a findViewById.  Maybe first thing in your onResume() implementation.